# import package and graphicspath do not work together

Tags: input, includegraphics, import

Hi I tried to use the `import` command from the `import` package to not conflict with the relative paths in the imported file. However, this doesn't seem to work with `\graphicspaths`.

Here the structure of my directories

```
folder/
   a5version/
       a5version.tex
   source/
       master.tex
       chapters/
          chapter1.tex
       images/
          buw.pdf
```

Then the a5version.tex looks like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{import}
\import{./../source/}{master.tex}
```

the master.tex looks like

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphics}
\graphicspath{{./images/}}
 
\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter 1}
\input{./chapters/chapter1.tex}
\end{document}
```

and chapter1.tex looks like

```
This is the first chapter. Here is a graphic:
\includegraphics{buw.pdf}
```

When I try to compile `a5version.tex` I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Package pdftex.def Error: File `buw.pdf' not found: using draft setting.
```

Is there a way to fix this? I mean clearly I could just don't use `\graphicspath` and use `includegraphics{./images/buw.pdf}`, but this is a little bit inconvenient.

Comment: personally I wouldn't use import just make source your current dorectory and do `pdflatex ../a5version/a5version` then all filepaths are naturally relative to the master document. But if you want to use it I would assume addding `\graphicspath{{images/}{../source/images/}}` probably works.

Comment: i don't understand how it helps to change the location of a5version, because if I compile a5version.tex, then everything has to be relative to a5version.tex. However, the second part combined with the answer of gernot does what I want.

Comment: no paths are not relative to a file they are relative to the working directory of the tex process, so if you are in the directory containing master when you start pdftex then all paths are relative to that location even if the document specified on the commandline is elsewhere

Comment: @DavidCarlisle okay I didn't know that, but I usually compile in a latex environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
\graphicspath{{./images/}}
```

by

```
\makeatletter
\graphicspath{{\import@path/images/}}
\makeatother
```

You have to make sure that `master.tex` is always `\import`ed, not just `\input`, as otherwise `\import@path` will not be defined.

Comment: combining this with the comment to my question also allows this input the master file in the same directory.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek Why do you have to change the graphics path? Just use `\import{.}{master.tex}`

Comment: thats true, but if for example i want to add in master file `if\IsAfive0 \documentclass{report}\fi` such that the master file can be compiled own its own, then it is relevant

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek In this case you could add `\makeatletter\def\import@path{.}\makeatother` between `\documentclass{}` and `\fi`. But it is debatable whether this is simpler.

Comment: ah thanks. this is also possible. I did it the other way around. I changed the graphicspath only if IsAfive equals 1.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek I've added another solution using the `subfiles` package.

Answer (score 1):

The OP mentions in the comments that the original file should also be compilable on its own. In this case, the `subfiles` package may help to hide a bit of the machinery.

```
% a5version/a5version.tex
\PassOptionsToClass{a5paper}{book}
\documentclass[../source/master]{subfiles} % get preamble from ../source/masters.tex
% ... additional settings for a5version.tex ...
\begin{document}
\subfile{../source/master}% import contents of document, skipping its preamble
\end{document}

% source/master.tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfiles}
% subfiles package has to be loaded before \graphicspath
\graphicspath{{images/}}% graphics path relative to this file
\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter 1}
\input{./chapters/chapter1.tex}% input path relative to this file
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this is really what I have been looking for.

Comment: I again get the error message: ERROR: Package pdftex.def Error: File `buw.pdf' not found: using draft setting.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek Do you have the `\graphicspath` statement after `\usepackage{subfiles}`?

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek Otherwise, check whether you have recent versions of LaTeX and the `subfiles` package. Both should be dated October 2020 or newer.

Comment: ah i found the error. interestingly for `\graphicspath` neither the package `graphics` nor `graphicx` is necessary, but for this solution it is. Thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek Oh yes, `\graphicspath` requires `graphics` or `graphicx`. Several packages load `graphicx` implicitly, so it may seem that it is not required. Just try `\documentclass{article}\graphicspath{...}`: you will get the error "unknown macro `\graphicspath`"

Comment: Can I also change the documentclass with this method? E.g. if my master file is `book` can I make the a5version `scrbook`?

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek I've added another answer ...

Answer (score 0):

In yet another comment, Nathanael asks for a solution in the case that the document should be typeset with another document class, but remaining unchanged otherwise. If the two versions are in the same folder, then

```
% a5version.tex
\documentclass[a5paper]{scrbook}
\newcommand\skipdocumentclass[2][]{\let\documentclass\origdocumentclass}
\let\origdocumentclass\documentclass
\let\documentclass\skipdocumentclass
% ... additional definitions for a5version
\input{master}
```

should do the trick. If the main document is somewhere else and inputs/includes/imports other files itself, you will need something like

```
% a5version/a5version.tex
\documentclass[a5paper]{scrbook}
\RequirePackage{import}
\newcommand\skipdocumentclass[2][]{\let\documentclass\origdocumentclass}
\let\origdocumentclass\documentclass
\let\documentclass\skipdocumentclass
% ... additional definitions for a5version
\import{../source}{master}
```

If the main document uses `\graphicspath` and is not in the same folder as its clones, load the package `subfiles` in the preamble before `\graphicspath`.

```
% source/master.tex
\documentclass...
...
\usepackage{subfiles}
...
\graphicspath{..}
```

The `subfiles` package redefines `\graphicspath` such that it add `\import@path`, which ensures that the path specifications are interpreted relative to the folder of `master.tex`, not to the one of the file in the latex command.