# TeXstudio: create chapters in subfolders and figurtes in subsubfolders

Tags: input, include, folders

I'd like to setup my document as such:
/folder/main.tex  %includes the preamble  info
/folder/chapter1/CH1.tex
/folder/chapter1/Figures/<all_Ch1pictures.png>
/folder/chapter2/CH2.tex
/folder/chapter2/Figures/<all_Ch2pictures.png>
/folder/chapter3/CH3.tex
/folder/chapter3/Figures/<all_Ch3pictures.png>

In main.tex I have \graphicspath{ {./Figures/}} in the pre-amble, but this only works if I store all pictures in folder/Figures/
I'd like to have the pictures stored in each chapter-directory.
How can I do this?

Comment: IMHO you are searching for package [`import`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/import). See also [import package and graphicspath do not work together](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/617813/277964).

Comment: you could reset graphicspath at the start of each chapter or not use it at all and use `\includegraphics{chapter2/Figures/all_Ch2pictures.png}`

Comment: so you're saying i could place   
\graphicspath{ {./Figures/}}   
at each start of a new chapter (=file )